# Microsoft Access (2013) Frontend & MySQL Backend Linked Tables Default Value Issue

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have an Access `(.accdb)` frontend which is connected to a MySQL backend using linked tables.

I have tried everything, but I can not get the Default Values from the MySQL table definitions to be pulled into Access.

Has anyone ever ran into this issue before?

Comment: Can you provide details? What do you mean by "pulled into access"? Can you at least list a few of the items from the "everything" that you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Until someone posts answer to this question, a workaround can be to specify default values in the controls itself.

For example, if you have a text box with date, and you want to fill it with today's value when form loads, In the `Default Value` property of the text box, specify `=Date()`

This method is better, as the front-end then is database independent. When in future you migrate DB, the front-end will work as expected.

Comment: I'll +1 this as potentially the *solution*, not a workaround, since some table definition defaults are impossible for a front-end tool to properly supply, particularly `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  That's the database server clock's timestamp as of the time of insert, and for Access to *display* it would necessarily mean access would also have to *insert* it, and it would no longer be the *database* clock's timestamp at time of insert... or if Access didn't write it, the value shown to the user creating the record would not necessarily match what was actually inserted.